# Домашний сервер

Tags: telegram-bot, сервер, веб-сервер

Имеется немного детский вопрос:

Могу ли я использовать физический(домашний) сервер как веб-сервер(Поднять 2-3 статичных сайта) и файловое хранилище(Помойку) одновременно. Так-же есть 3 телеграмм бота, которые висят в облаке, но было бы классно так-же крутить их на нем(Через трюки-вебхуки)?

Как рассчитать нагрузку? Какое нужно железо и подойдет-ли пропускная способность сети? Планирую всё поднимать на Debian GNU/Linux

*Я ещё совсем молодой frontend разработчик(До разработчика ещё далеко, скорее кодер), вообще не думал, что меня потянет в эту степь, но вот я тут*

Comment: Если провайдер предоставляет постоянный IP, то без проблем, в противном случае тоже можно но сложнее чуть-чуть. Что касается нагрузки, пропускной способности и прочего, тот тут нужно тестировать..

Comment: Очевидно, всё зависит от того, кто и сколько использует это всё добро. Если боту никто не пишет и файлы никто не качает, то и на кофеварке заработает. А если миллионы сообщений и скачиваний в секунду, то и целого дата-центра может не хватить

Comment: Примерные цифры до 1000 обращений к ботам, до 5000 обращений к сайтам... А файловая помойка на 3-х человек(Возможность резать скорость при сильной нагрузке)